# Calculate Stoploss Percentage in Pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, algorithmic-trading

I know how to get the calculate the stoploss 245.6 but I don't know how to get the percentage 2.08% ... Can someone please help me get the formula for the percentage?

[image]

I used the following formula to get the stoploss 245.6 pips

```
pips = (abs(1.18047 - 1.15591) / syminfo.mintick) / 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The percentage formula can be written in different forms, it is essentially an algebraic equation involving three values that you can turn into a function, for example:

```
//@version=5
indicator("", format = format.percent)

percent(value1, value2) => float(value1)/float(value2) * 100

val1 = 1.15591
val2 = 1.18047

percentChange = 100 - percent(val1, val2)

plot(percentChange) // 2.08
```